# Webscraping HTML-tags including the ones inside all links

Tags: python, regex, hyperlink, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup with Python 3.5 and I'm trying to scrape a website for all h-tags (so all h1, h2.. etc.). My problem is to make the program open other links on the website to scrape their tags too.

So let's say I have a website with a navigational menu with some links that go throughout the website and all include h-tags of some sort. How would I go about scraping all of them on my selected site?

This is the code i'm using so far to just scrape h1-tags in a specific url:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://dsv.su.se/en/research"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

h1_data = soup.find_all("h1")

for item in h1_data:
    print (item.contents[0])
```

I hope I made myself clear enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

using your example url, we can get all the urls from the `HeadRowMenu` and use a loop to extract all the h1's from each page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = "http://dsv.su.se/en"

base = "http://dsv.su.se"


def crawl(start, base):
    r = requests.get(start)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    hs = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"]
    menu_links = [urljoin(base, a["href"]) for a in soup.select("#HeadRowMenu a")][1:]
    for h in hs:
        yield soup.find_all(h)
    for lnk in menu_links:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(lnk).content)
        for h in hs:
            yield soup.find_all(h)
```

If we run it:

```
In [17]: print(list(chain.from_iterable(crawl(url, base))))

[<h1 class="visuallyhidden">Department of Computer and Systems Sciences</h1>, <h1>
<a href="/en/about/news/improve-your-digital-competences-on-line-with-eskills-match-1.278510">Improve your digital competences on-line with eSkills Match</a>
</h1>, <h1>
<a href="/en/about/news/envisioning-equality-in-computer-science-tomorrow-today-1.272045">Envisioning Equality in Computer Science - Tomorrow Today</a>
</h1>, <h1>
<a href="/en/about/news/egovlab-develops-online-democracy-1.271839">eGovlab develops online democracy</a>
</h1>, <h1>
<a href="/en/about/events/vinnova-and-dsv-invite-you-to-a-seminar-about-horizon-2020-1.266104">Vinnova and DSV invite you to a seminar about Horizon 2020</a>
</h1>, <h1>
<a href="/en/about/news/significant-increase-of-applicants-for-international-programmes-1.265744">Significant increase of applicants for international programmes</a>
</h1>, <h1>News</h1>, <h2>Semester start information</h2>, <h2>Meet our students</h2>, <h1 class="visuallyhidden">Education</h1>, <h1>Welcome to the education web at DSV!</h1>, <h1>Master's Programmes at DSV</h1>, <h2>
    Master's Programmes in English:</h2>, <h1 class="visuallyhidden">Research</h1>, <h1>Research highlights</h1>, <h2>Research news</h2>, <h1 class="visuallyhidden">About us</h1>, <h1>About DSV</h1>, <h2>Sweden's oldest IT department</h2>, <h2>Interdisciplinary education and research</h2>, <h2>Right in the middle of one of the world's leading ICT clusters</h2>, <h1 class="visuallyhidden">Internal</h1>, <h1>Internal</h1>, <h2>Semester start information</h2>, <h2>Meet our students</h2>]
```

If you want to literally scrape every link on the site you should look at [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), it id not trivial to do as you cannot just blindly visit every link you find as that could literally bring you anywhere and loop infinitely. You would need to make sure that you are only visiting the domain you want which you can do with scrapy quite easily. have a look at the [crawlspider](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=rules#crawlspider).

To roll your own:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin


class Crawl:
    def __init__(self, start_url, allowed, base, select):
        self.start_url = start_url
        self.base = base
        self.allowed_domain = allowed
        self.crawled = set()
        self.select = select

    def start(self):
        r = requests.get(self.start_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
        menu_links = [urljoin(self.base, a["href"]) for a in soup.select(self.select)]
        for lnk in menu_links:
            yield from self.crawl(lnk)

    def crawl(self, lnk):
        r = requests.get(lnk)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
        hs = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"]
        page_links = (a["href"] for a in soup.select("a[href]"))
        joined = (urljoin(base, lnk) if lnk.startswith("/en/") else lnk for lnk in page_links)
        for lnk in filter(lambda link: link.startswith("http"), joined):
            if lnk not in self.crawled:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(lnk).content,"lxml")
                for h in hs:
                    yield soup.find_all(h)
            self.crawled.add(lnk)
```

A sample run:

```
In [2]: from itertools import chain    
In [3]: url = "http://dsv.su.se/en"    
In [4]: base = "http://dsv.su.se"    
In [5]: crawler = Crawl(url, "dsv.su.se", base, "#HeadRowMenu a") 

In [6]: for h in chain.from_iterable(crawler.start()):
   ...:          print(h)
   ...:     
<h1 class="visuallyhidden">Institutionen för data- och systemvetenskap</h1>
<h1>
<a href="/omdsv/evenemang/dsv-50-%C3%A5r-digitala-aff%C3%A4rer-%C3%B6ppet-jubileumsseminarium-1.274298">*DSV 50 år* - Digitala affärer - öppet jubileumsseminarium </a>
</h1>
<h1>
<a href="/omdsv/nyheter/premi%C3%A4r-f%C3%B6r-vandringsdramat-exil-fria-poeter-p%C3%A5-flykt-1.278502">Premiär för vandringsdramat Exil - fria poeter på flykt</a>
</h1>
<h1>
<a href="/omdsv/nyheter/nu-b%C3%B6r-det-st%C3%A5-klart-att-n%C3%A5got-m%C3%A5ste-g%C3%B6ras-1.277680">Nu bör det stå klart att något måste göras </a>
</h1>
<h1>
<a href="/omdsv/nyheter/hur-enkelt-%C3%A4r-det-f%C3%B6r-fbi-att-kn%C3%A4cka-en-iphone-utan-apples-hj%C3%A4lp-1.277546">Hur enkelt är det för FBI att knäcka en Iphone utan Apples hjälp?</a>
</h1>
<h1>
<a href="/omdsv/nyheter/1-av-2-vill-l%C3%A5ta-staten-hacka-sig-in-i-datorer-1.277367">Svårt att backa tillbaka från ökad övervakning</a>
</h1>
<h1>Senaste nyheterna</h1>
<h2 class="category">Kommande evenemang</h2>
<h2>Information inför terminsstart</h2>
<h1 class="visuallyhidden">Other languages</h1>
<h1>Other languages</h1>
<h2>
    Information in Chinese and Russian</h2>
<h2>Contact The Administration of Studies</h2>
<h1 class="visuallyhidden">Department of Computer and Systems Sciences</h1>
<h1>
<a href="/en/about/news/improve-your-digital-competences-on-line-with-eskills-match-1.278510">Improve your digital competences on-line with eSkills Match</a>
</h1>
<h1>
<a href="/en/about/news/envisioning-equality-in-computer-science-tomorrow-today-1.272045">Envisioning Equality in Computer Science - Tomorrow Today</a>
</h1>
<h1>
<a href="/en/about/news/egovlab-develops-online-democracy-1.271839">eGovlab develops online democracy</a>
</h1>
<h1>
<a href="/en/about/events/vinnova-and-dsv-invite-you-to-a-seminar-about-horizon-2020-1.266104">Vinnova and DSV invite you to a seminar about Horizon 2020</a>
</h1>
<h1>
<a href="/en/about/news/significant-increase-of-applicants-for-international-programmes-1.265744">Significant increase of applicants for international programmes</a>
</h1>
<h1>News</h1>
<h2>Semester start information</h2>
<h2>Meet our students</h2>
...................................
```

Obviously if you want to go deeper you will need to add more logic storing all links in one structure and looping until it is empty. Something like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from time import sleep

class Crawl:
    def __init__(self, start_url, allowed, base, select):
        self.start_url = start_url
        self.base = base
        self.allowed_domain = allowed
        self.crawled = set()
        self.select = select
        self.urls = set()

    def start(self):
        r = requests.get(self.start_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
        menu_links = [urljoin(self.base, a["href"]) for a in soup.select(self.select)]
        print(menu_links)
        for lnk in menu_links:
            yield from self.crawl(lnk)

    def filter_urls(self, soup):
        page_links = [a["href"] for a in soup.select("a[href]")]
        joined = (urljoin(base, lnk) if lnk.startswith("/en/") else lnk for lnk in page_links)
        return set(filter(lambda lnk: self.allowed_domain in lnk, joined))


    def crawl(self, lnk):
        r = requests.get(lnk)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
        hs = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"]
        self.urls.update(self.filter_urls(soup))
        while self.urls:
            nxt = self.urls.pop()
            if nxt not in self.crawled:
                try:
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(nxt).content, "lxml")
                except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                    print(e.strerror)
                    self.crawled.add(nxt)
                    continue
                self.urls.update((self.filter_urls(soup) - self.crawled))
                for h in hs:
                    yield soup.find_all(h)
            self.crawled.add(nxt)
            sleep(.1)
```

That will visit every link on the site that has `dsv.su.se` in the url but be warned there are a lot of links to scrape so be prepared to wait for a while.

Answer (score -1):

here is a demo version(untested) that does what you describe.
Basically you add the discovered url in a queue
and continue until all links are crawled

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import deque

seen = set()
queue = deque(['http://dsv.su.se/en/research'])
while len(queue):
    url = queue.popleft()
    if url not in seen:
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
        h1_data = soup.find_all("h1")
        for item in h1_data:
            u = item.contents[0]
            queue.append(u)
        seen.add(url)
```

I think you need something similar.